# Apache Flink: Can we get windowStartTime and windowEndTime from the windowed join apply function?

Tags: join, apache-flink, flink-streaming, sliding-window

I am implementing a simple join of two streams in Apache Flink. I am in need of windowStartTime and windowEndTime in the windowed join apply function. Is there any way to get them? I tried "getRuntimeContext()" but it didn't work.

```
            streamA.join(streamB)
            .where(new KeySelector<String, String>() {
                @Override
                public String getKey(String str) throws Exception {
                    return str;
                }
            }).equalTo(new KeySelector<String, String>() {
                @Override
                public String getKey(String str) throws Exception {
                    return str;
                }
            }).window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(windowSize), Time.seconds(windowSlideStep)))
            .apply(new JoinFunction<String, String, String>(){
    @Override
    public String join(String x, String y) throws Exception {

                    Long windowStartTime = ???
                    Long windowEndTime = ???
           }});
```

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't possible.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thank you so much, you are always very helpful. In that case, how do we know that an output belongs to which window, specially when using sliding window with small slide steps?